# Iteration order for hashtable in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it guaranteed that the hash table will be iterated (`keys %hashtable`) in fixed order when running in the same environment with the same operation sequence(also the same contained data)?

Answer (score 5):

No. Even if on some versions it's true in practice, there has never been any *promise* of hash keys being produced in any particular order, and developers have always been warned about depending on any given order. Since version 5.18, the order for any two runs will almost always be different.

However, what *is* promised is that `keys %hash` and `values %hash` will produce their results in corresponding order (the *n*th key corresponding to the *n*th value), as long as `%hash` isn't modified in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of perl version and environment.

In version 5.18 behavior was changed and order can be changed even in two queries one after another
This can be controlled with the PERL_PERTURB_KEYS environment variable

you can look here for more info

https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#PERL_PERTURB_KEYS-environment-variable-added

Comment: Just to be clear, using this information in new code is unwise in the extreme.  PERL_PERTURB_KEYS should be thought of as a crutch to get poorly written old code to work in v5.18 until you have the time to fix it.